# using or after and in Linq to entities lambda expression

Tags: linq-to-entities

This query is ok:

```
from a in context.employee.where(a=>a.time > sometime && a.time.addmin(60) < sometime || a.time < someothertime).
```

But if I add () to make sure the and comes before the or, compiler doens't recognized the 2nd a:

```
from a in context.employee.where((a=>a.time > sometime && a.time.AddMinutes(60) < sometime) || a.time < someother time)).
```

This time: 
Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'lambda expression' and 'lambda expression'

How can use use OR in linq to entities with and in the same where clause ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

shouldnt it be

```
from a in context.employee.where(a=> (a.time > sometime && a.time.AddMinutes(60) < sometime) || a.time < someother time).
```

note the a => in your non working one is within inner brackets